# Using MIDI Fighter Classic as a GIMP controller

Tags: usb, alsa, gimp, midi, peripherals

I'd like to use a MIDI device to select my most commonly used tools in GIMP. I see that I can add a midi controller in the Input Devices preferences, although I've been unable to get this  working. My research so far has led me [here](http://www.tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html) and to the [GIMP website](https://www.gimp.org/unix/howtos/gimp-midi.html).

The MIDI Fighter has been set to channel 1 with the MF Utility.

I've created a MIDI input for GIMP via the GIMP Input Devices preferences menu. It's listening on channel -1 (so it should receive input from all channels
`~/.gimp-2.8/controllerrc` contains:

> `(GimpControllerInfo "MIDI Fighter"
>       (stock-id "gimp-controller-midi")
>       (enabled yes)
>       (debug-events yes)
>       (controller "ControllerMidi"
>           (device "alsa")
>           (channel -1))
>       (mapping))`

I can see that the MIDI Fighter is connected with `cat /proc/asound/cards`

> ```
>  0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
>                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xef340000 irq 143
>  1 [Classic        ]: USB-Audio - Midi Fighter Classic
>                       www.djtechtools.com Midi Fighter Classic at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, full speed
> ```

I've connected GIMP to the Midi fighter with `aconnect 20 128` and 
`aconnect -lo` shows that they are routed to each other.

> ```
> client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
>     0 'Midi Through Port-0'
> client 20: 'Midi Fighter Classic' [type=kernel,card=1]
>     0 'Midi Fighter Classic MIDI 1'
>   Connecting To: 128:0
> client 128: 'GIMP' [type=user,pid=11073]
>     0 'GIMP MIDI Input Controller'
>   Connected From: 20:0
> ```

GIMP is not showing any MIDI input in the terminal or when attempting to "grab events".

Is there a way I can have GIMP connect to my MIDI controller without having to enter "aconnect # #" each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading over the [MIDI how to](https://www.gimp.org/unix/howtos/gimp-midi.html) page of the GIMP website again, I noticed that I had overlooked this:

> OSS:
>
> The Open Sound System provides a device file for the raw MIDI events.
> You need to enter the name of this device file into the “Device” entry
> in the configuration (e.g. “/dev/midi00”).

Using `ls /dev` I determined that `/dev/midi1` is the device I need to connect GIMP  to the MIDI Fighter via OSS.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of GIMP is 2.10, and you do not need to muck around with configuration files. You can simply add a MIDI controller in the preferences window:

[image: GIMP input controllers - MIDI]

Then enter "alsa" as device name, and enable dumping events:

[image: GIMP MIDI controller configuration]

Then connect your MIDI controller to GIMP's port with `aconnect`.

If you have started GIMP from a console, you should now see information about all received note-on/-off and controller messages, e.g.:

```
Received 'MIDI Events' (class 'MIDI')
    controller event 'controller-007 (Controller 007)'
    (value event, value = 0.503937)
    doesn't map to action

Received 'MIDI Events' (class 'MIDI')
    controller event 'note-on-3c (Note 3c on)'
    (value event, value = 0.803150)
    doesn't map to action

Received 'MIDI Events' (class 'MIDI')
    controller event 'note-off-3c (Note 3c off)'
    (value event, value = 0.000000)
    doesn't map to action
```

Anyway, you don't need to dump events: press "Grab event", and then press the actual key or controller, and the corresponding entry in the Event list will be selected.
You can then use "Edit event" to assign some tool.

Comment: with ALSA as the device (as it is in the config file I posted)  I wasn't getting any input, while running via a terminal, with "dump events" enabled.. I've already tried exactly this before posting my question.

Comment: GIMP 2.8 is the officially supported version provided by UbuntuStudio packages at this time.